# how to redirect user on success of ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, redirect

I am using `twitter bootstrap` and I have a birthday `Modal` which asks user to enter their `date of birth`, the validation and inserting the data into database is working fine but i need to redirect user to another page (dashboard.php) on success, following is the ajax code i am using

```
$('#dobform').submit(function (e) {
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dobsubmit').button('loading');
    var post = $('#dobform').serialize();
    var action = $('#dobform').attr('action');
    $("#message").slideUp(350, function () {
        $('#message').hide();
        $.post(action, post, function (data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            if (data.match('success') !== null) {
                $('#dobform').slideUp('slow');
                $('#dobsubmit').button('complete');
                $('#dobsubmit').click(function (eb) {
                    eb.preventDefault();
                    $('#dob-form').modal('hide');
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#dobsubmit').button('reset');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I have tried using the following redirection code in `else` but it redirects the user regardless of error or not

```
window.location = "dashboard.php"
```

I have tried using the redirection inside

```
if (data.match('success') !== null) {

}
```

but this does not work either, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: @Jai I have tried on server side but it does not redirect

Comment: Redirecting server-side is nonsense for an AJAX request. What does `data` _actually_ contain (log it to console to see)? And why are you using `match` to check it?

Comment: @CBroe what else to use other than `match` this is what i am trying to do, if i get an error in response as the user to enter the valid information, if i am getting success message in response then i want to insert data in DB and redirect user to another page

Comment: `match` is for regular expressions. And if you are asked explicit questions, then please __answer__ them!

Comment: If you want to check if data is not null use: `if(data !== null)`  
or if you want to check if data is 'success': `if(data === 'success')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to do it, had to take out `match`

```
$('#dobform').submit(function (e) {
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dobsubmit').button('loading');
    var post = $('#dobform').serialize();
    var action = $('#dobform').attr('action');
    $("#message").slideUp(350, function () {
        $('#message').hide();
        $.post(action, post, function (data) {
            $('#message').html(data);
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#message').slideDown('slow');
            if (data == "Thankyou") {
                $('#dobform').slideUp('slow');
                $('#dobsubmit').button('complete');
                window.location = "dashboard.php";
                $('#dobsubmit').click(function (eb) {
                    eb.preventDefault();
                    $('#dob-form').modal('hide');
                });
            }
            else {

                $('#dobsubmit').button('reset');
            }
        });
    });
});
```